# Actionscript: Pseudo-Random Number creation with seeds

Tags: actionscript-3, random, perlin-noise

I am creating a function that returns a Perlin Noise Number in Flash.
For this function I must have a function that returns a random number from a static seed. Unfortunately the default Math.random in Actionscript can't do this..

I searched for a long time on the internet and I couldn't find a solution that fits my perlin-noise function.

I tried the following codes:

```
public static var seed:int = 602366;
public static function intNoise(x:int, y:int):Number {
    var n:Number = seed * 16127 + (x + y * 57);
    n = n % 602366;
    seed = n | 0;
    if (seed <= 0) seed = 1;
    return (seed * 0.00000166) * 2 - 1;
}
```

This function does create a Random number, but the seed changes all the time so this doesn't work with perlin noise.

```
public static function intNoise(x:int, y:int):Number {
    var n:Number = x + y * 57;
    n = (n<<13) ^ n;
    return ( 1 - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);  
}
```

I got this function from the Perlin Noise tutorial I followed: [Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), but it only seems to return 1.

### How can I create a function that always returns the same Pseudo-Random number when called with the same seed?

Comment: Does this [AS3 PRNG](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=162) work for you ?

Comment: No because the function only requires the seed when initializing, and I want to have a static function that uses a variable seed.

Comment: then modify it to fit your need

Comment: Can you show me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the random number generator mentioned in the link and it looks like this:

```
function IntNoise(32-bit integer: x)
    x = (x<<13) ^ x;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);
end IntNoise function
```

I translated it thus:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var seeds:Array =
            [ -1000, -999, -998, 7, 11, 13, 17, 999, 1000, 1001 ];

        public function Main() {
            for ( var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++ )
                trace( intNoise( seeds[ i ] ) );

            // Outputs: 1, 0, 0, -0.595146656036377, -0.1810436248779297,                                 
            // 0.8304634094238281, -0.9540863037109375, 0, 0, 1
        }

        // returns floating point numbers between -1.0 and 1.0
        // returns 1 when x <= -1000 || x >= 1001 because b becomes 0
        // otherwise performs nicely
        public function
        intNoise( x:Number ):Number {
            x = ( uint( x << 13 ) ) ^ x;
            var a:Number = ( x * x * x * 15731 + x * 789221 );
            var b:Number =  a & 0x7fffffff;
            return 1.0 - b / 1073741824.0; 
        }
    }
}
```